# Should I use external Configuration.xml file or just the web.config?

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-applications, configuration, web-config

For my web application, I have several startup config values that need to be stored on a config xml file and will be loaded up when the web starts. My question is should I use an external xml or just put all those values into the web.config file? And if I use the external xml then when should I load it and where should I save the values to (Application_Start method? save to Application['name']?). And when I change this xml file, I need to restart the whole application right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more details, I say use the web.config. That is why we have it :)

When you edit web.config, the change will be picked up on the next request.

*edit to address the comment*

If your config file is getting bloated, you can move sections to an external file.

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings configSource="appSettings.config" />   
   <connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.config" />
   <system.web>    
      <pages configSource="pages.config" />
      <httpHandlers configSource="httphandlers.config">
   </system.web>    
</configuration>
```

Comment: Say I have an email template, should I put it into the web.config also?

Comment: I do. I have edited the answer to address what to do it your config file starts to get large